# Why doesn't Mathematica simplify?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

Consider the following:

```
Simplify[Integrate[x^(a), {x, x1, x2}], x1 > 0 && x2 > 0 && a > 0]
```

Mathematica doesn't simplify this for me. I do not understand why.

It should return me x^(a+1)/a+1

Comment: If you'd like an indefinite integral, don't include the bounds of integration. If you'd like to integrate with assumptions, use the `Assumptions` option with `Integrate` -- it does not seem to populate those assumptions with the assumptions given to `Simplify` automatically.

Comment: `Integrate[x^(a), {x, x1, x2}, Assumptions -> (x1 > 0 && x2 > 0 && a > 0)]`?

Comment: If you use `Assuming` the assumptions are made available to both `Integrate` and `Simplify`, i.e., `Assuming[x2 > x1 > 0 && a > 0,
 Integrate[x^(a), {x, x1, x2}] //
  Simplify]`